# How to assign Keys to SKActions in Swift

Tags: key, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I was hoping someone would be able to help me with this problem. I can't seem to find a way to assign a key to an SKAction for Sprite Kit for the removeActionWithKey method. I have also tried assinging the action to a key in a dictionary but the program didn't recognize the key assignment and thus returned a nil value.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
var textureanimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(_walkingframes, timePerFrame: 0.1))
var dictionary = ["animation": textureanimation]
    object.runAction(actionForKey("animation"))

    var sequence = [SKAction.moveTo(tap_position, duration: time_duration),
        SKAction.runBlock{

            object.removeActionForKey("animation")}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can do it in the runAction method

```
sprite.runAction(myCoolAction, withKey: "Cool Action")
```

This will allow you to remove the action by name

```
sprite.removeActionForKey("Cool Action")
```

Just from experience, I'd recommend placing action string names in variables. It will cut down on the weird bugs from very slightly misspelled action names.

So an improved version of this is a class var

```
let coolActionName = "Cool Action"

// Your other code

// Run the action
sprite.runAction(myCoolAction, withKey: coolActionName)

// Time to remove the action
sprite.removeActionForKey(coolActionName)
```

Comment: Great answer @Jeremy. I suggest when working with keys, store strings as variables so Xcode would automatically brings it up. Also, this will prevent typo errors. So, let keyCoolActionName = "coolActionName" and call it via keyCoolActionName.