# Running an SKAction of a scene from a UIKit View

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

As actions can only be triggered by nodes

http://www.riptutorial.com/sprite-kit/example/21553/running-a-block-of-code-in-an-skaction

is it possible to access a node from UIKit to trigger this from outside?

Comment: Possibly. Can you elaborate on the tools you're using? Are you embedding HTML content from UIKit in a Swift application somehow?

Comment: hm no just coding in Swift 4, having a UIKit view that has a SKView as a subview

Comment: I can access the nodes but to make them run an action I need to pass them the action, but the only method I found that return an action requires the action key but I didn`t have luck getting it, someone suggested that when the node runs an action then the key will be set up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787252/how-to-assign-keys-to-skactions-in-swift but didn`t work for me

Comment: used notifications for now https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/

Comment: You need to go view->scene->node